# Building int[] of increasing size

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

What is the easiest way to build an array of integers starting at 0 and increasing until a given point?

*Background:* 
I have a `struct` that holds an `int[]` representing indexes of other arrays.

I would like to signify I want to use all indexes by filling this array with `int`s starting at 0 and increasing until `int numTotalIndexes;` I am sure there is a better way to do this than using a for loop.

Someone here showed me this little Linq trick

```
int[] numContacts = new int[]{ 32, 48, 24, 12};
String[][] descriptions = numContacts.Select(c => new string[c]).ToArray();
```

to build a jagged 2D array without loops (well it does, but it hides them and makes my code pretty) and I think there might be a nice little trick to accomplish what I want above.

Comment: Note that linq "without loops" is a complete misnomer, linq simply encapsulates the "looping" (or more accurately, iteration) inside `ToArray`.

Comment: Yeah, indeed. I'll make a little edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
int[] intArray = Enumerable.Range(0, numTotalIndexes).ToArray();
```

You:

> I am sure there is a better way to do this than using a for loop

Note that LINQ also uses loops, you simply don't see them. It's also not the most efficient way since `ToArray` doesn't know how large the array must be. However, it is a readable and short way.

So here is the (possibly premature-)optimized, classic way to initialize the array:

```
int[] intArray = new int[numTotalIndexes];
for(int i=0; i < numTotalIndexes; i++)
    intArray[i] = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand your question at all but if going by your first line what you want is

```
var MySequencialArray = Enumerable.From(0,howmanyyouwant).ToArray();
```